# SharePoint website name not changing in the start page after changing it from the sites settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-settings, bug

I have a SharePoint website which I changed its name from settings -> site information -> site name.

However, in SharePoint's start page where I can see the frequent and followed sites, that site's name didn't change.

I couldn't figure out why that's the case so I would really appreciate your help. Thought I'd give it some time but the same issue happened with a different site and I waited more than 10 days but still the name didn't change in the start page.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Please remember to accept the helpful answer if you resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue in my end.

As a workaround, you could unfollow the site then follow the site again, the site name will change in the start page.